# How to take all the dropdown options?

Tags: selenium

In selenium 2.0, i am trying to get the list of drop down values and to print it. How to do this? I am trying below:

```
for (int i = 1;i<=13;i++)
        {


            WebElement values=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@rel='i']/a/span[@class='pull-left']"));
            System.out.println(values);
        }
```

@rel= '1', '2' should go like this.. so that i can print all the values.

But this is not working.. How to use the 'i' in this element.

Thanks

Comment: you should add some html if you want answers. Based on what you have posted so far, i doubt that anybody can possibly help you

Comment: Some how i managed to get this..                                    for (int i = 1;i<=13;i++)
  {
      
   //System.out.println("//li[@rel=" + i +"]/a/span[@class='pull-left']");
   String values=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@rel=" + i +"]/a/span[@class='pull-left']")).getText();
   System.out.println(values);
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hard coding no of options value you can get that dynamically.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li/a/span[@class='pull-left']"));
//iterate above list to get all option values
for(WebElement eachOption : options) {
 System.out.println(eachOption.getText());
}
```

Comment: findElements method will Find all elements within the current context using the given locator. http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)

Answer (score 0):

Some how i managed to get this..

```
for (int i = 1;i<=13;i++) { 
//System.out.println("//li[@rel=" + i +"]/a/span[@class='pull-left']"); 
String values=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@rel=" + i +"]/a/span[@class='pull-left']")).getText(); 
System.out.println(values); }
```